# Rank these time complexities

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity

Can someone please help me rank these time complexities ?

functions with same order have to be given same rank.

```
Take n > 1

rank => functions :
1 => n log_2(n) , 10n log_10(n)
2 => n^(log_2log_2(n))
3 => n^2
4 => n^3
5 => 2^(log_50(n))
6 => n!
7 => (n + 1)!
```

The above is how I have ranked. Can any one correct it if I have made a mistake ? Also if there is any website to visualize these functions, it would be great.

Comment: I don't think anyone will do your homework for you. Check here for answers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: I was asking for help in validating my answer. thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n^(log_2log_2(n)) is going to grow faster than n raised any constant eventually so it comes after n^2 and n^3

there's a relation between all logarithms log_c1(x) = log_c2(x)/log_c2(c1) so 2^(log_50(n)) will be equal to 2^(log_2(n)/log_2(50)) 2^log_2(n) = n, so that comes before n^2.

Comment: Actually `2^(log_50(n))` grows even slower than `n`

Comment: `log_50(n) = log_2(n)/log_2(50)`, so `2^(log_50(n)) = 2^(log_2(n)/log_2(50)) = n^(1/log_2(50))`